# ASP.NET Core 6 API deployed to Azure w/F1 free App Plan: returns 500

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a ASP.NET Core 6 API deployed to Azure using the F1 free App Plan.  Calling any endpoint returns a status code of 500.

I used the Log stream feature.  Below my signature I will post the whole thing but the highlights are these:

- IIS was not able to access the web.config file for the Web site
- The authenticated user does not have permission to use this DLL.
- Install the .NET Extensibility feature if the request is mapped to a managed handler

My ASP.NET Core 6 API does not have a web.config file at all.  It has appsettings.json file but not web.config file.  Should I add one?

Below my sig I will add the full log. I appreciate any help!
Thanks, Dan

```cs
2022-11-08T14:52:02  Welcome, you are now connected to log-streaming service. The default timeout is 2 hours. Change the timeout with the App Setting SCM_LOGSTREAM_TIMEOUT (in seconds).
```

IIS Detailed Error - 500.0 - Internal Server Error

#### HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error

##### The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.

##### Most likely causes:

- IIS received the request; however, an internal error occurred during the processing of the request. The root cause of this error depends on which module handles the request and what was happening in the worker process when this error occurred.
- IIS was not able to access the web.config file for the Web site or application. This can occur if the NTFS permissions are set incorrectly.
- IIS was not able to process configuration for the Web site or application.
- The authenticated user does not have permission to use this DLL.
- The request is mapped to a managed handler but the .NET Extensibility Feature is not installed.

##### Things you can try:

- Ensure that the NTFS permissions for the web.config file are correct and allow access to the Web server's machine account.
- Check the event logs to see if any additional information was logged.
- Verify the permissions for the DLL.
- Install the .NET Extensibility feature if the request is mapped to a managed handler.
- Create a tracing rule to track failed requests for this HTTP status code. For more information about creating a tracing rule for failed requests, click  [here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=66439).

##### Detailed Error Information:

```cs
Module AspNetCoreModuleV2Notification ExecuteRequestHandlerHandler aspNetCoreError Code 0x00000000 Requested URL https://FlowCastApi20221108072930:80/api/cohortPhysical Path C:\home\site\wwwroot\api\cohortLogon Method AnonymousLogon User Anonymous
```

##### More Information:

This error means that there was a problem while processing the request. The request was received by the Web server, but during processing a fatal error occurred, causing the 500 error.

[View more information »](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=62293&IIS70Error=500,0,0x00000000,14393)

Microsoft Knowledge Base Articles:

```cs
2022-11-08 14:52:09.840 +00:00 [Error] Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection: An error occurred using the connection to database 'flowcast-dev' on server 'tcp:greenshoes-dev.database.windows.net,1433'. 
2022-11-08 14:52:09.853 +00:00 [Error] Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query: An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type 'FlowCastApi.Model.DataContext'.Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot open server 'greenshoes-dev' requested by the login. Client with IP address '20.49.104.46' is not allowed to access the server. To enable access, use the Windows Azure Management Portal or run sp_set_firewall_rule on the master database to create a firewall rule for this IP address or address range. It may take up to five minutes for this change to take effect.at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CheckPoolBlockingPeriod(Exception e)at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.WaitForPendingOpen()--- End of stack trace from previous location ---at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternalAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternalAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean errorsExpected)at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(AsyncEnumerator enumerator, CancellationToken cancellationToken)at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()ClientConnectionId:ec461d75-6cc2-4508-9541-47d546a25d0dError Number:40615,State:1,Class:14ClientConnectionId before routing:f9b3f656-f418-4e09-ac95-a3ab8ace69a6Routing Destination:e194283991a1.tr29051.eastus1-a.worker.database.windows.net,11042Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot open server 'greenshoes-dev' requested by the login. Client with IP address '20.49.104.46' is not allowed to access the server. To enable access, use the Windows Azure Management Portal or run sp_set_firewall_rule on the master database to create a firewall rule for this IP address or address range. It may take up to five minutes for this change to take effect.at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CheckPoolBlockingPeriod(Exception e)at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.WaitForPendingOpen()--- End of stack trace from previous location ---at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternalAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternalAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean errorsExpected)at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(AsyncEnumerator enumerator, CancellationToken cancellationToken)at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()ClientConnectionId:ec461d75-6cc2-4508-9541-47d546a25d0dError Number:40615,State:1,Class:14ClientConnectionId before routing:f9b3f656-f418-4e09-ac95-a3ab8ace69a6Routing Destination:e194283991a1.tr29051.eastus1-a.worker.database.windows.net,11042 
2022-11-08 14:52:09.872 +00:00 [Error] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpServer: Connection ID "15204152343613408971", Request ID "800006cc-0000-d300-b63f-84710c7967bb": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot open server 'greenshoes-dev' requested by the login. Client with IP address '20.49.104.46' is not allowed to access the server. To enable access, use the Windows Azure Management Portal or run sp_set_firewall_rule on the master database to create a firewall rule for this IP address or address range. It may take up to five minutes for this change to take effect.at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CheckPoolBlockingPeriod(Exception e)at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.WaitForPendingOpen()--- End of stack trace from previous location ---at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternalAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternalAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean errorsExpected)at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(AsyncEnumerator enumerator, CancellationToken cancellationToken)at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)at FlowCastApi.Controllers.BaseController`1.GetAllAsync(Int32 count, Int32 skip, String searchTerm, String sortBy) in C:\_source\Greenshoes\api_dotnet\FlowCastApi\Controllers\Base\BaseController.cs:line 41at lambda_method5(Closure , Object )at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.AwaitableObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContextOfT`1.ProcessRequestAsync()ClientConnectionId:ec461d75-6cc2-4508-9541-47d546a25d0dError Number:40615,State:1,Class:14ClientConnectionId before routing:f9b3f656-f418-4e09-ac95-a3ab8ace69a6Routing Destination:e194283991a1.tr29051.eastus1-a.worker.database.windows.net,11042
```

Comment: Please share your Program.cs and `appsettings.json` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created `ASP.Net CORE Web API` and deployed to Azure App service. Able to access the endpoint without any issues.

- Make sure you have checked the below options while creating the App.
  [image]

***My Program.cs***

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.ConfigureSwaggerGen(setup =>
{
    setup.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Microsoft.OpenApi.Models.OpenApiInfo
    {
        Title = "Weather Forecasts",
        Version = "v1"
    });
});

var app = builder.Build();
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();
```

In `Azure Portal` => `API Management service` => `API's`, check whether you can see the created API.

[image]

> My ASP.NET Core 6 API does not have a web.config file at all. It has appsettings.json file but not web.config file. Should I add one?

When we deploy .Net CORE Web App to Azure, `web.config` file will be generated by default. You can check it in KUDU `DebugConsole`.
Your `Azure App Service`=>`Advanced Tools` => `Go` => `Debug Console`

[image]

- In `web.config` file , change `modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2"` to `modules="AspNetCoreModule"`

```
<add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
```

Your error indicates the issue while connecting to DB.

Make sure you have configured `SQL Server Database`.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Harsitha for the thorough response.  My problem ended up being that I needed to mark my database server as allowing connections to Azure services.