# Getting HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error after deploying .NET 7 Web API to Azure App Service

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-webapi

I am facing an issue after deploying my .NET 7 Web API to Azure App Service. Whenever I try to access the API endpoints, I receive the following error(Log Stream):

Swagger page is opening fine, only getting this error when trying to access the API endpoint.

> #### HTTP
> Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
>
> ##### The page cannot be
> displayed because an internal server error has
> occurred.
>
> ##### Most
> likely causes:
>
> - IIS received the request; however, an
>   internal error occurred during the processing of the request. The root
>   cause of this error depends on which module handles the request and
>   what was happening in the worker process when this error
>   occurred.
> - IIS was not able to access the web.config file for
>   the Web site or application. This can occur if the NTFS permissions
>   are set incorrectly.
> - IIS was not able to process
>   configuration for the Web site or application.
> - The
>   authenticated user does not have permission to use this DLL.
> - The request is mapped to a managed handler but the .NET
>   Extensibility Feature is not installed.
>
> ##### Things you can try:
>
> - Ensure that the NTFS permissions for the web.config file are
>   correct and allow access to the Web server's machine account.
> - Check the event logs to see if any additional information was
>   logged.
> - Verify the permissions for the DLL.
> - Install the .NET Extensibility feature if the request is mapped
>   to a managed handler.
> - Create a tracing rule to track failed
>   requests for this HTTP status code. For more information about
>   creating a tracing rule for failed requests, click [here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=66439).
>
> ##### Detailed Error
> Information:
>
> Module   AspNetCoreModuleV2Notification   ExecuteRequestHandlerHandler   aspNetCoreError
> Code   0x00000000

In Configuration's general settings I am already specified the .NET 7

[image]

Also added this web.config file in the solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
        <system.webServer>
            <handlers>
                <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
            </handlers>
            <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\TestV2.WebApi.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile="\\?\%home%\LogFiles\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
</configuration>
```

I am deploying this web api from Visual Studio using publish settings file.

Can anyone provide insights into what might be causing this error and how to resolve it? I suspect it could be related to the deployment configuration or some specific settings required for .NET 7 on Azure App Service.

Comment: Can you issue request via swagger? Can you issue requests when starting locally on the dev machine?

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride, Only swagger page is opening, but when I am trying to access API, above error logged in "Log Stream" in Azure, On my localhost everything is working fine.

Comment: On a IIS you have very limit access to the IIS resources like the file system.  This is very common that code works on a localhost but fails when installed on IIS.  If you are using the file system instead place files on a Network drive where uses have permission to read and write.

Comment: It seems weird to me that you have a `Web.config` even though you're configuring .net7 in azure. Most netcore apps will have `appsettings.json` files instead. Are you sure you're not actually building a .net framework project that you are trying to host using .net7?

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride I am also using `appsettings.json` files only, I think this `web.config` added by earlier developer by mistake, I just checked we're not using this `web.config` file anywhere in this web api, all settings coming from `appsettings.json` file only. Do you think this `web.config` file creating issue?

Comment: Azure portal in the "App Service logs" page: have you tried activating "Web server logging", lowering the "Level" to "Verbose", and/or enabling "Detailed error messages" aready?

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride Yes! I did that already, but no luck, it is showing same error no other details.

Comment: Could you please share the code once.

Comment: `I think this web.config added by earlier developer by mistake,`. Once we deploy the WebApp, `Web.config` file will be created in the deployed app root folder. The problem is not with the `Web.config` file, that is created by default.

Comment: In the `Web.config` file change the `stdoutLogEnabled` to true and check the created log file in `home\LogFiles\stdout` path, it displays the complete error message.

Comment: I think the error is because if this line of code.  
    stdoutLogFile="\\?\%home%\LogFiles\stdout"
I think this folder structure does not exist on the AppService.

Comment: Yes, the logs will be created in the `home\LogFiles` folder.

Answer (score 1):

Since you could open Swagger page normally, so I think you have deployed the application successfully.

You also mentioned the issue will occur when you try to access the API endpoint. Could check the `weatherforecast` first and confirm it work or not.

[I found a good tutorial about how to deploy the webapp via using VS2022](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74373544/7687666) which written by [Harshitha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19648279/harshitha). His answer is very useful, and I also recommend you to check `Service Dependencies`. It must be configured in local, so it works well in local.

[image]

#### Steps

Please allow me summarize the content above, you could follow the steps to fix the issue.

1. Test the default endpoint, `/weatherforecast`.
2. Check the `Service Dependencies`.
3. View detailed error message logs

   1. [View detailed error message logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-dotnet-visual-studio#detailederrorlogs)
   2. [Azure App Service - Configure Detailed Error Logging](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/azure-app-service-configure-detailed-error-logging/)
4. Re-create a brand new app service , and try again. There is a very small chance that the service of azure app service may encounter a special situation, which may cause an exception when your app is created.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I found useful when I encountered a similar error, if you are using a database, is to go to the server on azure => firewall => exceptions and activate "Allow Azure resources to access this server". For some reason an Azure app is unable to access an Azure database server even after connecting to it with the connection string.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error too. When I deployed the web api, you need to go to the AzureSQL database and activate the Allow Azure resources to access this server option.